# Failed to find data adapter error using a Pandas Dataframe and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am building an ANN model to predict customer churn.
`X` is a list and `y` is a single array. I am getting the following error on  `model.fit()`:

```
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>*
```

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(26, input_shape=(26,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [68], in <cell line: 16>()
     10 opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
     12 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
     13               loss='binary_crossentropy',
     14               metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 16 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorfl\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorfl\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py:985, in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    982 adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]
    983 if not adapter_cls:
    984   # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
--> 985   raise ValueError(
    986       "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    987       "input: {}, {}".format(
    988           _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    989 elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    990   raise RuntimeError(
    991       "Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for "
    992       "handling inputs. Found multiple adapters {} to handle "
    993       "input: {}, {}".format(
    994           adapter_cls, _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Try to add these two lines before `model.fit()`: `X_train= np.asarray(X_train)` and
`y_train = np.asarray(y_train)`

Comment: `X` should not be a list, it should be an array, right? It's capital X because X is a matrix of data values